# Validate String in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I need to validate a string to see if the string is in **BOLD** and also if the text is the color green.

```
Root_TaxDataSummary.SlvObject("FederalBalanceDueAmount").GetROProperty("text")

   refundBold = InStr(1,Root_TaxDataSummary,"?")

  If refundBold > 0
      'Pass
  Else
      'Fail
  End If
```

Comment: Could you add a little more information?  What kind of objects are you working with - are they web pages or native windows apps, or what?  (We can't tell what type Root_TaxDataSummary is...  or did you typo and meant to write Root_TaxDataSummary = SlvObject?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead property `text`, I think you should use other properties, for example `innerhtml` or `outerhtml`. Then, looking for patterns such as `/b`depends on your web object.